# How can I get the fqdn of a running TcpListener

Tags: c#, tcplistener

I have a server represented by a TcpListener, and I need its FQDN.
Is there a way I can get it?
The listener is defined as:

```
TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 27015);
```

Comment: what yoy mean "i have a server" so it is your localhost?

Comment: you can get the ip address from FQDN but not FDQN from ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My short answer would be a simple method constructing the FQDN. This may fail if your server implements more than one network interface.

```
public string FQDN() {
  string host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();
  string domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;      

  return host + "." + domain;
}
```

---

Since you're initializing your `TCPListener` with `IPAddress.Any`, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63.aspx)

> the underlying service provider will assign the most appropriate network address.

That means, you have to wait until a client is connected to retrieve the FQDN, as you don't know beforehand what network address you will get assigned (and once again, if your server implements multiple network interfaces you don't know which one the client will connect to).
Three steps would be neccessary to obtain the FQDN of the network interface the client connected to:

1. get the local endpoint of the client (as an [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx))
2. get the IP-address of the endpoint
3. get the host entry for this IP-address (via [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143998.aspx))

In code it looks like this:

```
//using System.Net
//using System.Net.Sockets

TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 27015);
tcpListener.Start();

//code to wait for a client to connect, omitted for simplicity

TcpClient connectedClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient(); 

//#1: retrieve the local endpoint of the client (on the server)
IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = (IPEndPoint)connectedClient.Client.LocalEndPoint;

//#2: get the ip-address of the endpoint (and cast it to string)
string connectedToAddress = clientEndPoint.Address.ToString();

//#3: retrieve the host entry from the dns for the ip address
IPHostEntry hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(connectedToAddress);

//print the fqdn
Console.WriteLine("FQDN: " + hostEntry.HostName);
```

You may write #1, #2 and #3 in one single line:

```
Dns.GetHostEntry(((IPEndPoint)connectedClient.Client.LocalEndPoint).Address.ToString()).HostName);
```